# Delooping an R code for calculation of overlapping intervals

Tags: c++, r, for-loop, intervals

I have data of this format (snippet):

```
       SW_Release deviceType     configStartDate       configEndDate
 1:   04.05.00         21 2005-11-03 19:12:36 2006-02-28 10:19:27
 2:   04.05.00         16 2005-11-04 03:59:05 2006-02-28 10:19:27
 3:   04.05.00         20 2005-11-04 03:59:06 2006-02-28 10:19:27
 4:   04.05.00         15 2005-11-04 03:59:06 2006-02-28 10:19:27
 5:   04.05.00         19 2005-11-04 03:59:06 2006-02-28 10:19:27
 6:   04.05.00         17 2005-11-04 03:59:06 2006-02-28 10:19:27
 7:   04.07.03         16 2006-02-28 10:19:27 2006-03-29 01:00:39
 8:   04.07.03         20 2006-02-28 10:19:27 2006-03-29 01:00:41
 9:   04.07.01         15 2006-02-28 10:19:27 2006-03-29 01:00:41
10:   04.07.01         19 2006-02-28 10:19:27 2006-03-29 01:00:41
11:   04.07.01         17 2006-02-28 10:19:27 2006-03-29 01:00:42
12:   04.07.01         21 2006-02-28 10:19:27 2006-03-29 01:00:42
13:   04.07.01         18 2006-02-28 10:19:27 2006-03-29 01:00:42
14:   04.07.04         16 2006-03-29 01:00:40 2006-05-01 16:07:49
15:   04.07.04         20 2006-03-29 01:00:41 2006-05-01 16:07:50
16:   04.07.02         15 2006-03-29 01:00:41 2006-05-01 16:07:50
17:   04.07.02         19 2006-03-29 01:00:41 2006-05-01 16:07:51
18:   04.07.02         17 2006-03-29 01:00:42 2006-05-01 16:07:51
19:   04.07.02         21 2006-03-29 01:00:42 2006-05-01 16:07:51
20:   04.07.02         18 2006-03-29 01:00:42 2006-06-01 09:45:36
21:   04.07.04         16 2006-05-02 09:47:57 2006-06-01 09:45:25
22:   04.07.04         20 2006-05-02 09:47:57 2006-06-01 09:45:28
23:   04.07.02         15 2006-05-02 09:47:58 2006-06-01 09:45:31
24:   04.07.02         19 2006-05-02 09:47:58 2006-06-01 09:45:32
25:   04.07.02         17 2006-05-02 09:47:58 2006-06-01 09:45:34
26:   04.07.02         21 2006-05-02 09:47:58 2006-06-01 09:45:35
27:   04.07.05         16 2006-06-01 09:45:27 2006-08-14 17:54:15
28:   04.07.05         20 2006-06-01 09:45:29 2006-08-14 17:54:15
29:   04.07.06         15 2006-06-01 09:45:31 2007-12-12 11:03:00
30:   04.07.06         19 2006-06-01 09:45:33 2007-12-12 11:03:00
31:   04.07.03         17 2006-06-01 09:45:35 2006-08-14 17:54:16
32:   04.07.03         21 2006-06-01 09:45:35 2006-08-14 17:54:16
33:   04.07.04         18 2006-06-01 09:45:37 2007-12-12 11:03:00
34:   04.07.06         16 2006-08-14 17:54:15 2007-12-12 11:02:59
35:   04.07.06         20 2006-08-14 17:54:15 2007-12-12 11:02:59
36:   04.07.04         17 2006-08-14 17:54:16 2007-12-12 11:03:00
37:   04.07.04         21 2006-08-14 17:54:16 2007-12-12 11:03:00
38:   04.05.12         14 2011-06-17 15:40:13 2012-05-24 11:43:24
```

I need to add up all the intervals (between second-to-last and last columns), but, as you can see, some rows have overlapping or partially overlapping intervals.

Before I add up all the days, I need to convert the full dataset (from which the above snippet came) into something like:

```
accumulated data:
       configStartDate       configEndDate
1: 2005-11-03 19:12:36 2007-12-12 11:03:00
2: 2011-06-17 15:40:13 2012-05-24 11:43:24
total days: 934.296
```

Here’s my R code for doing this (it has to be R, although I am considering re-writing it in C++ and using RCPP):

```
merge_intervals <- function(interval_dt){
  interval_dt <- interval_dt[order(configStartDate), list(configStartDate, configEndDate)]

  new_dt <- interval_dt[1, list(configStartDate, configEndDate)]

  for (i in 2:dim(interval_dt)[1]) {
    buff <- interval_dt[i, list(configStartDate, configEndDate)]

    if (new_dt[dim(new_dt)[1], configEndDate] >= buff[, configStartDate]){
      if(new_dt[dim(new_dt)[1], configEndDate] >= buff[, configEndDate]){
        next
      }
      else{
        new_dt[dim(new_dt)[1], configEndDate := buff[, configEndDate]]
      }
    }
    else {
      new_dt <- rbind(new_dt, buff)
    }
  }

  return(new_dt)
}
```

Right now the whole thing takes about 0.16 seconds to run (with other calculations), but, for 3000 unique assets, that creates 8 minutes calculation time overhead.

How do I transform that `for` loop into something faster to reduce calculation time? Thanks!

Comment: It should be possible to do this vectorised. How do you want to handle overlapping intervals? Ignore the overlap or join the intervals into a single new interval and only consider that new interval?

Comment: Sorry, but your example doesn't make it clear to me exactly what operation you want to perform. How do you get from the 10 rows you displayed in the first block (all of which are in the year 2006) to the two in the second block (which span 2005-2012)? Could you describe exactly how to get from sample input to expected output?

Comment: I edited sample to include all rows to make it clearer.

Comment: Based on a quick look, have you checked `foverlaps()` from data.table package?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = 1:3,
  start = Sys.time() + c(0, 1000, 3000),
  end = Sys.time() + c(1500, 2000, 4000)
)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(
    overlap = lead(start, 1, default = TRUE) < end, 
    interval = cumsum(overlap)
  ) %>% 
  group_by(interval) %>% 
  summarise(start = min(start), end = max(end)) %>% 
  mutate(delta = end - start) %>% 
  summarise(total = sum(delta))
```